# Изменение коллекции при добавлении новой строки в CheckListBox

Tags: c#, winforms

Вопрос по c# winforms vs2010: На форме `Form1` есть `CheckListBox1`, в который добавляются строки с помощью кнопки `btn_add`, которая в свою очередь открывает форму `Form2` с данными в `DataGridView1`. По кнопке `button1` (на форме `Form2`) происходит добавление новой строки в `CheckListBox1`. Новая строка помещается в коллекцию `persons`, к которой привязываются три label-а (`label_users_0`, `label_users_1`, `label_users_2`). Код ниже работает только для одной добавляемой строки в `CheckListBox1`. Как изменить коллекцию при добавлении в `CheckListBox1` новых строк?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();

        private void btn_add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                var form2 = new Form2();
                if (form2.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    CheckListBox1.SetSelected(CheckListBox1.Items.Add(form2.getItem()), true);

                    persons.Add(new Person { Name = form2.getItem() });

                    var listBox = ((ListBox)CheckListBox1);
                    listBox.DataSource = persons;
                    listBox.DisplayMember = "Name";

                    label_users_0.DataBindings.Clear();
                    label_users_1.DataBindings.Clear();
                    label_users_2.DataBindings.Clear();

                    label_users_0.DataBindings.Add("Text", persons, "Value_users_0");
                    label_users_1.DataBindings.Add("Text", persons, "Value_users_1");
                    label_users_2.DataBindings.Add("Text", persons, "Value_users_2");

                     label_users_0.Text = form2.getItem();
                    label_users_1.Text = form2.getItem1();
                    label_users_2.Text = form2.getItem2();
                }
                form2.Close();
                form2.Dispose();
        }

    }


public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            button1.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        }

        public string getItem()
        {
            String Tab = (String)DataGridView1[0, DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Value;
            return Tab;
        }

        public string getItem1()
        {
            String Tab1 = (String)DataGridView1[1, DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Value;
            return Tab1;
        }

        public string getItem2()
        {
            String Tab2 = (String)DataGridView1[2, DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Value;
            return Tab2;
        }

    }


public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Value_users_0 { get; set; }
    public string Value_users_1 { get; set; }
    public string Value_users_2 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Она же и так меняется при добавлении строк тут `persons.Add(new Person { Name = form2.getItem() });` или я не догоняю в чем вопрос

Comment: При добавлении в CheckListBox1 второй строки выходит ошибка "Изменение коллекции элементов невозможно, если задано свойство DataSource". Надо чтобы при добавлении второй и более строки в CheckListBox1, к каждой строке в CheckListBox1 были привязаны свои значения из 3-х Label-ов.

Comment: `к каждой строке в CheckListBox1 были привязаны свои значения из 3-х Label-ов` label-ов 3, а строк может быть хоть 100, как вы хотите 3 строки привязать к 100 строчкам?

Comment: с помощью DataBindings

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, может для решения моей задачи надо использовать BindingList?

Comment: Так не понятно что вы сделать то хотите. Label - выводит информацию об 1 элементе, CheckListBox - это список элементов. Что и к чему вы биндить хотите, что в Label вам надо вынести то? Как вы список элементов хотите запихать в label? Что у вас этот label должен показывать то?

Comment: Задача следующая: в CheckListBox по кнопке добавляется строка (строка - это значение из выделенной строки первого столбца DataGridView: DataGridView1[0, DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Value). Вместе с добавленной строкой в CheckListBox, хотелось бы перенести с привязкой значения из текущей строки первого, второго и третьего столбцов DataGridView: DataGridView1[0, DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Value, DataGridView1[1, DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Value и DataGridView1[2, DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Value  в  label_users_0.Text, label_users_1.Text и label_users_2.Text соответственно.

Comment: Я верно понял - вам надо выводить инфу о последнем добавленном элементе в checklistbox в те три label'a?

Comment: Если возможно, то хотелось бы выводить значения для всех добавленных элементов в checklistbox. Т.е., например, в checklistbox добавлены две строки (два элемента), тогда при выделении 1-ой строки - показать ее значения в label-ах, при выделении 2-ой строки показать значения в label-ах для второй строки и т.д.

Comment: То есть вам надо показывать поля `выделенного` в checklistbox элемента в 3 лейблах, верно? Не последнего добавленного, а именно выделенного.

Comment: Верно, выделенного.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы в винформах обновлять значения лейблов данными из выделенного элемента в CheckedListBox, не надо никаких биндингов, можно просто подписаться на событие `SelectedIndexChanged`. Как пример:

Допустим есть класс

```
public class Data
{
    public string Name { get; set;}
    public int Id { get; set;}
}
```

Создадим форму с CheckedListBox и 2 лейблами. Подпишемся на событие `SelectedIndexChanged` и будем обновлять лейблы когда выделенный эелемент меняется.

```
class MyForm : Form
{   
    public MyForm()
    {
        var cbl = new CheckedListBox() {Width = 400, Height = 400};
        cbl.DisplayMember = "Name";

        var objects = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(x => new Data() { Id = x, Name = $"Name of {x}"}).ToArray();

        cbl.Items.AddRange(objects);

        this.Width  = 600;
        this.Height = 500;


        var lbid = new Label() {Width = 100, Left = 410, Height = 15};
        var lbname = new Label() {Width = 100, Left = 410, Top = 15};

        cbl.SelectedIndexChanged += (sender, args) => {
            var item = cbl.SelectedItem as Data;
            if (item != null)
            {
                lbid.Text = item.Id.ToString();
                lbname.Text = item.Name;
            }
            else lbid.Text = lbname.Text = string.Empty;
        };


        this.Controls.Add(cbl);
        this.Controls.Add(lbid);
        this.Controls.Add(lbname);
    }
}
```

В действии

[image: В действии]